# Mat-select input composed object

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular11

I am struggling to input a composed value into a select. Let's say our object only contain an **ID** and a **name**, an usual way to have a working select would be to do :

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Placeholder</mat-label>
   <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let i of fooCollection" [value]="i.id">
         {{i.name}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now to feed a value, I found [this working example in the documentation](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rypvrbvvogk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts) which simply add a `[(value)]` option into the `mat-select` tag, but since we got a composed object here it doesn't work anymre.

Any idea on how to solve this ? Many thanks !
Kev'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:
Typescript:

```
      /** @title Select with 2-way value binding */
  @Component({
    selector: 'select-value-binding-example',
    templateUrl: 'select-value-binding-example.html',
  })
  export class SelectValueBindingExample {

  myOptions = [
    new MyOptions('name1','description1' ),
    new MyOptions('name2','description2' ),
    new MyOptions('name3','description3' ),
  ]


  selectedOption = this.myOptions[2]

  }//Cls

  //-----------------------------------------------------//

  class MyOptions{
    constructor(
      public name:string,
      public description:string
    ){}
  }
```

Html:

```
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(value)]="selectedOption">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let myOption of myOptions" [value]="myOption">
          {{myOption.description}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <p>You selected: {{selectedOption|json}}</p>
```

When you add the line `<mat-select [(value)]="selectedOptionName">` it will "collect" what ever value went into the [value] in this line  `<mat-option *ngFor="let myOption of myOptions" [value]="actualValueGoesHere">`.
And the you can uise the value however you like.

To set an initial value just set selectedOption = this.myOptions[2] (or what ever the first choice shouold be)

Comment: Well I tried what you mean in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6lwijf?file=src/app/select-value-binding-example.ts) but it doesn't input a value intro the selects

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: My whole question is how to input values into the select in order to display a default one and allow a user to hit a "save" button without changing the dropdown value if it's okay for him !

Comment: As an example how to have your option 2 displayed on loading of the page

Comment: I've edited the answer. YOu just need to set  selectedOption  in your .ts  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6lwijf-vrh46b?file=src/app/select-value-binding-example.ts

Comment: @KevinHeirich No problem